# how to create table with values summed by year in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

The postgres database format is:

```
year    product     sales   account
2013    bread       10      001
2013    bread       5       002
2013    peanut      5       001
2013    jam         4       001
2013    jam         5       002
2014    bread       12      001
2014    bread       6       002
2014    peanut      6       001
2014    jam         5       001
2014    jam         3       002
```

The desired output is to create a table by year with the product total summed.

```
product     2013    2014        
bread       15      18
peanut      5       6
jam         9       8
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: you have to use crosstab function.

Comment: @Roy it can be done other ways and the crosstab function is a part of a tablefunc extension, which must be installed

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
Product ,
Sum (case when year =2013 then 1 else 0 end) 2013,
Sum (case when year =2014 then 1 else 0 end) 2014
From your table 
Group by 
Product;
```

Comment: It should be `then sales else 0 end`  not `then 1 else 0 end`

Answer (score 1):

first you store the result of the sum sales as t1

```
select product, year, sum(sales) as sales
  from table
  group by 1,2
  order by 1,2
```

then you use crosstab()

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
  'SELECT product, year, sales
   FROM   t1
   ORDER  BY 1,2')  
AS foo("product" text, "2013" int, "2014" int);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see there are several questions about creating crosstab queries with variable amount of columns. It is impossible for regular query but can be done using [refcursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html).

Lets create function which

1) constructs query like:

```
select
  name_field,
  sum(value_field) filter (where column_field = c1) as col_1,
  sum(value_field) filter (where column_field = c2) as col_2,
  ...
from
  table
group by
  name_field
```

where c1, c2, ... are constants for our columns

and 2) returns cursor for this query:

```
create or replace function ct(
  in p_sql text, -- Data providing query
  in p_name_field varchar, -- Field with titles for rows 
  in p_column_field varchar, -- Field with titles for columns
  in p_value_field varchar, -- Field with numeric data
  p_cursor refcursor) returns refcursor as $$
declare
  q text;
  cols varchar[];
  c varchar;
begin
  -- Collect column names
  execute 'select array_agg(distinct ' || p_column_field || '::varchar) from (' || p_sql || ') t' into cols;

  -- Build query
  q := 'select ' || p_name_field;
  for c in (select unnest(cols)) loop
    q := q || ', sum(' || p_value_field || ') filter (where ' || p_column_field || '::varchar = ' || quote_literal(c::text) || ') as col_' || c;
  end loop;
  q := q || ' from (' || p_sql || ') t group by ' || p_name_field || ' order by ' || p_name_field;

  open p_cursor for execute q;
  return p_cursor;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

Thats it. Now we can use this function for the OP's data like:

```
begin;
select ct('select * from sales', 'product', 'year', 'sales', 'ct_cur');
fetch all in ct_cur;
-- Yet another usage example:
select ct('select * from sales', 'product, account', 'year', 'sales', 'ct_cur_acc');
fetch all in ct_cur_acc;
-- And another one:
select ct('select * from sales', 'account, year', 'product', 'sales', 'ct_cur_prod');
fetch all in ct_cur_prod;
commit;
```

And results is:

```
 product | col_2013 | col_2014 
---------+----------+----------
 bread   |       15 |       18
 jam     |        9 |        8
 peanut  |        5 |        6
(3 rows)

 product | account | col_2013 | col_2014 
---------+---------+----------+----------
 bread   | 001     |       10 |       12
 bread   | 002     |        5 |        6
 jam     | 001     |        4 |        5
 jam     | 002     |        5 |        3
 peanut  | 001     |        5 |        6
(5 rows)

 account | year | col_bread | col_jam | col_peanut 
---------+------+-----------+---------+------------
 001     | 2013 |        10 |       4 |          5
 001     | 2014 |        12 |       5 |          6
 002     | 2013 |         5 |       5 |           
 002     | 2014 |         6 |       3 |           
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this.  A crosstab may be the easiest, but it requires the tablefunc extension to be installed, which you may not have superuser privilege for.

Another way is to use subqueries, which makes adding a new year 2 simple copy/paste/update:

```
WITH 
products as (
  select product from sales group by product
),
sums AS (
   select product, sum(sales) total_sales, year
   from sales
   group by product, year
)

SELECT 
   products.product,
   "2013".total_sales as "2013",
   "2014".total_sales as "2014"
FROM products
LEFT JOIN sums "2013" ON(products.product="2013".product and "2013".year=2013)
LEFT JOIN sums "2014" ON(products.product="2014".product and "2014".year=2014)

ORDER BY product
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b8dff/9)