# use one table as a rule while performing select query on the other table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table name `test`

```
first       last
raj         kumar
raj        patel
```

there is hundreds of row in this table.

I have another table called `class` having all the names that are present in the `test` table and its marks for each subject.

```
class_id    first_name   last_name   subject     marks
 1       raj           kumar       physics    70
 1       raj           kumar       chemistry  70
 1       raj           patel       physics    80
 1       raj           kumar       math       90
 1       raj           kumar       computer   80
 1       raj           patel       chemistry  90
 1       raj           patel       math       100
 2       raj           kumar       physics    70
 2       raj           kumar       chemistry  70
 2       raj           patel       physics    80
 2       raj           kumar       math       90
 2       raj           kumar       computer   80
 2       raj           patel       chemistry  90
 2       raj           patel       math       100
```

Now i want to know the total marks of each student present in the `test` table in below format :.

```
class_id    raj.kumar    raj.patel
 1          310           270
 2           n             m
```

So there will be `n` number of columns in the resulting tbale

for this particular case we can write

```
 select class_id
    sum(case when first_name = 'raj' and last_name = 'Kumar' then marks else 0) as "raj.kumar",
    sum(case when first_name = 'raj' and last_name = 'patel' then marks else 0)as "raj.patel"
    from class 
    group by class_id
```

Since number of students is not fixed which is present in the `test` table. so i don't want to hardcode the first and last name in my query. 
I want something like this which could be able to calculate marks for all the students which are present on `test` table.

```
 select class_id, 
    for(i = 0; i < test.size; i++)
     sum(case when first_name = i.first and last_name = i.last then marks else 0 ) as i.first|| '.' ||i.last,
    from class
    group class_id
```

How to write query or stored procedure for this
thanks in advance.

I am using postgresql.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35447184/593144). In your case it could be `select ct('select * from test', 'class_id', 'first_name || last_name', 'marks', 'ct_cur'); fetch all in ct_cur;`

Answer (score 0):

For all students?

What is wrong with:

```
select class_id, first_name, last_name, sum(marks)
  from class
group by class_id, first_name, last_name;
```

So you want a crosstab.  Here the main problem is that the planner needs to know how many columns and what their types are before starting.  So the bad news is there is no direct way to do this.

So you have a few options:

1. look at the `tablefunc` extension and dynamically generate your query around the `crosstab()` function
2. Use `xml` or `json` types and return objects or documents rather than records.
3. Use my query above and a client-side tool like excel to do the crosstab for you.
4. (edit) You can dynamically generate SQL in a stored procedure, and return a refcursor, but that brings you back to the problems just moving your "client" code generation into a function.

**EDIT** To be clear your problem is a planner limitation.  You cannot have expand a column list into a variable number of columns.  So you have to generate the SQL from outside the db.  **You cannot handle a dynamic number of columns directly in SQL.**

Now, I would highly recommend using the crosstab() function from the tablefunc extension because this simplifies conceptually the result quite a bit.  If you have to do this manually (please don't) you can write a query generator in pl/perl or pl/pgsql by selecting from the other table, and then use pl/pgsql's EXECUTE into a cursor.  You can then return a `refcursor.`  This is not ideal because the client then has to `FETCH` from the returned refcursor.

So your first point is to decide on where you are going to generate the SQL code that will run.  Will this be in a database client?  Or in dynamic SQL (with a requirement that the client FETCH rows separately from running the function)?

Comment: But the format of the table i want is different. i want all the names to be appear in the column as i mentioned above. So please guide me to write the query to achieve that . Thanks

Comment: Ah so you want a crosstab

Comment: This can be achieved with the help of CASE statement without going into cross tab. I have written query for the same above of that particular case, but i want the case statement to be generated with the help of test table. that too is mentioned in the last part with the help of a loop. but how to write query for the same that's what my concern is .. Thanks.